# How to test my 'magento' project on localhost?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, magento

Don't judge me that 'you don't even search anything' ...
Actually, I read and read this post :
[enter link description here](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2014/11/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x-yosemite/)

But I'm new to web project (I have only experience developing ios and android) , I don't know what I have to take a next step.

I have 'MAGENTO' project so my mission is to get accustomed to this project by testing on my localhost.

But I feel unkind for the post above because of my less understanding of web.

You can blame me, but please **Tell me What I don't know...**

I feel crazy because **I don't know what I don't understand**

What I've done is below :

- Installation of php version 5.6
- Having total project of magento of our service
- Check apache is installed : 
  Server version: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix)
  Server built: Jul 22 2015 21:03:09

One thing I think I am aware of is that I do not know how to connect my magento project and localhost...

Comment: I recommend to use PHP 5.5 as PHP 5.6 is not officially supported by Magento. For simplicity you can use xamp. You should import the live DB to localhost phpmyadmin.Move you code files to htdocs folder in xampp. Then change the base urls in Magento database.

Comment: @Muk Ok, thank you for your help... What I'm missing is that how to 'Move my code files to htdocs folder in xampp'? what is htdocs?... And How to import db to localhost phpmyadmin? I have experience making DBs and tables at phpMyAdmin but what is the meaning of live DB? Ofcourse, when i make a db and a table at phpMyAdmin , there is no data at first . this is my problem

Comment: **SO is not a teaching portal**, It's not about "blaming" or "judging" it's purely and simply not the goal of SO and therefor doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 1):

First as @muk Said. install xampp.

it is hard to tell you how to install magento on local machine because you are not aware of web.

[install magneto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dUgra62yOBw)

I am providing you a video please see that and I think you will get success.
BTW below are the steps to install magento on local xampp/wampp.

1. download and extract magento
2. put magento folder in htdocs folder (C:\xampp\htdocs\  if you install xampp in c drive)
3. open browser and hit localhost/phpmyadmin (make sure your mysql and apache are running)
4. create a database
5. now open another tab and hit url localhost/magento
6. a setup wizard will show there , enter required information

and that all. For more [information](https://ironion.com/installing-magento-on-xampp-2/).

Answer (score 0):

http://insync.co.in/how-to-install-magento-on-wamp-server-localhost-localcomputer/

This has all the info you need. If you still face issues, update your question with info about where you are stuck at and what error you see.